# Did Donald Trump say this about his daughter and wife?

Tags: quotes, donald-trump

If you Google for the phrase "Is it wrong to be more sexually attracted to your own daughter than your wife?", you will find quite a few sites, some of them reputable publications purporting that Donald Trump asked that question.

Snopes is quiet, so can anyone say definitively whether he did say this, or whether it is just speculation/a smear campaign? I know that he has made other questionable remarks about this daughter, so wonder about the truth of this allegation.

---

Example from [BuzzFeed](https://www.buzzfeed.com/tamerragriffin/trump-asked-if-its-wrong-to-be-attracted-to-his-daughter)

> Washington Post columnist Richard Cohen wrote that President-elect Donald Trump once asked, “Is it wrong to be more sexually attracted to your own daughter than your wife?” — but the quote was quietly removed before the syndicated column was published Tuesday.
>
> Trump was reportedly referring to his daughter, Ivanka, who was 13 years old at the time.
>
> The quote was circulated Monday in a draft of Cohen's piece “Our Next President, The Godfather" that was sent to outlets that syndicate the column, a source told BuzzFeed News. The quote did not appear in the later, final version of the piece carried by the Post and other outlets.
>
> Cohen's column details the president-elect’s increasingly blurred familial and political ties as he prepares to enter the White House.
>
> The reporting appeared in an advance version of the column that was circulated on Monday for publication on Tuesday and thereafter. It appeared as an aside after the introduction of Jared Kushner, which still appears in the final column:
>
> > Jared Kushner, our Tom Hagen, who married Trump's stunning daughter
> >     Ivanka — "Can I ask you something?" Trump asked someone I know, about
> >     his then-13-year-old kid, "Is it wrong to be more sexually attracted
> >     to your own daughter than your wife?" -- has lately lost some of this
> >     Boy Scout aura. It turns out Kushner's admission to Harvard was
> >     preceded by his father's $2.5 million pledge.

Comment: Since this was supposedly said in a private unrecorded conversation with an unnamed person, I don't see any way to prove or disprove it.

Comment: "His daughter and wife" - should this be edited to "his daughter and his wife" for clarity?

Comment: Suggesting that his daughter was also his wife? Lol +1

Comment: Should *which* wife he meant also be specified?

Comment: He has multiple wifes?! Is he a Muslim?

Comment: 1. There are several religions in the US that allow polygamy, and the most prominent one isn't Islam. 2. Parallel vs Sequential.

Comment: IC IC. Thansk for clarifying (+1)

Comment: So Buzzfeed is what passes for reputable publication in anti-Trump circles these days?

Comment: Strangely, I couldn't find any mention of it on that other bastion of truth, Breitbart. There's plenty of mentions out there; Buzzfeed was just one of them. I am ***not*** saying that I believe it. I understand that it is difficult to prove a negative, but if you can find a good rebuttal, you could post that as an answer. If no one can prove that it did happen, then I will gladly award the answer to a creditable rebuttal

Comment: @Peter: [Polygamy is illegal in the USA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamy#United_States), regardless of whether you are a Mormon, Muslim, or Atheist. You may have only one valid marriage license. [Polyamory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyamory), on the other hand, is legal.

Comment: Trump did say that he would be dating his daughter Ivanka if he wasn't married. You can find this on youtube.

Comment: @Peter if you're thinking of Mormonism, the main branch of it doesn't currently allow polygamy.

Comment: I like that "currently" :-) "No longer" means those days are gone forever; "currently", sound like "we're just waiting till the time is right to bring it back" :-)

Comment: Given that Washington Post decides not to publish the claim because it presumably doesn't match their sourcing standards and they don't have enough confidence in it's veracity and the Washington Post is the only primary source for the claim I don't see how this question can get a good answer and there isn't really a notable claim here. The BuzzFeed article doesn't make a direct claim that Trump said this.

Comment: Judaism also allowed polygyny at one point.  Most religions now accept the concept of multiple marriages so long as they are done serially rather than in parallel (divorce before subsequent marriages so only one at a time).  Trump has been married three times in that fashion.  He has two ex-wives and one current wife.  Both his ex-wives have daughters with him.  This particular story claims to be about a statement he allegedly made regarding his first wife and her daughter.

Comment: So, no one can say whether t'rump said this or not?